# Data management in MMORPG

Tags: java, client

I'm planning to write in JAVA simple, but easy to develop in future MMORPG. 
I know more or less how it should looks like, but I have some questions:

1. **Which kind of data should have client?** I know that, for example, server informs client if "that field" is free or not, but what about loading map? Client contains sprites etc., but should they also have map files or server should tell client where is the grass and where is water etc...
2. **How to keep data by server?** Players should be represented as files in one folder where server have to find right file, open it, get data and send it back for many players? Maybe database server + database + sql would be better idea?

Any ideas/knowledge about MMORPG structure?
Is Java a good choice for 2D MMORPG?

Answer (score 1):

MMO's are not easy programs to develop. It sometimes takes experienced teams years to develop one, and the questions you ask here don't seem to indicate you are a very experienced programmer. Having said that, I would suggest taking a look here:

- http://slick.ninjacave.com/
- http://www.13thmonkey.org/~boris/jgame/

These resources might be good starting points and get you up to speed quickly, but I'd suggest looking for a good tutorial on how to sync client/server data, en get a bit up to speed on programming Java in general.

Comment: I don't think he want to develop and market a MMORPG but it is just a programming excercise for himself.

Answer (score 0):

I developed Browsergames in the past. Usually it is a good idea to put "static" data (data that doesn't change very often, like map layouts) into the client, so that you don't need to resend it every time.

I would definitly prefer a database (some sql or nosql) to file-based storage. If you wan't to improve you coding skills and make them more marketable than definitly go for a database.

If you really want to release a simple game, than I would go for html5 as frontend. The graphic capabilities of JAVA a pretty limited. Also nearly nobody would download your game prior to playing it.